# Trying to write a post statement using HTTPUrlConnection which is gzip encoded but getting 400 response

Tags: java, post, gzip, httpurlconnection

I am trying to send a gzip encoded data using post but getting a 400 response every time

I tried the following code

```
conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", parameters[1]);

conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Encoding", "gzip");

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(messageBody.length());

GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);
                    gzip.write(messageBody.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

os.write(baos.toByteArray());

os.close();

gzip.close();

conn.connect();
int res = conn.getResponseCode();
```

The response code is always 400. Kindly help.

Comment: Do you have the response body, or server log to see why you have a 400 ?

Comment: Instead of using UrlConnection, it is better to HttpClient to post. You can use HttpClient, RestTemplate in Spring or Jesey client. Besides what is the end point url that you are sending.

Comment: httpclient is deprecated. I need to use httpurlconnection only.

Comment: The content of the header is empty if I perform the above code.